# In how many different ways can r elements be picked from a set of n elements if repetition is allowed and order of picking does not matter?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My approach gives me $\frac{n^r}{r!}$ but the answer given is $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm inclined to go with your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you are allowed to choose a total of $r$ candies from $n$ **types** of candies.

For each of the $n$ types, go on saying **yes** until you don't want any more, and then say **no** and move on to the next type.

Of course, you may say **no** straight away to any type if you don't want it, and you don't need to say **no** after the $n{th}$ because there is no next type.

So there will be $r$ of **yes** and  $(n-1)$ of **no** whichever way you choose, and the only decision you need to take is where to place the **yes's** in the sequence of $n-1 +r$ elements,

thus # of choices $=\dbinom{n+r-1}{r} = \dfrac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$

---

This method is called ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), and in the usual "stars and bars" explanation:

$\Large\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast\ast\ast\ast$

The "stars" stand for the $r$ **yes's**, and the "bars" for the $n-1$ **no's**

Answer (score 1):

The number of permutations $r!$ is not correct for all selections of $r$ elements, because permuting identical elements does not make a difference.

**HINT :-**

Think about number of solutions of:-
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=r,\space x_1,x_2,...,x_n\in\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$$

Since the order does not matter, all you have to worry about is no. of times an element is choosed. You choose first element $x_1$ times, second $x_2$ times and so on. You need to choose $r$ times in total. So their sum is $r$. You may never select a particular element, hence $x_i$ may be zero as well.

How to solve this further:- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-many-solutions-does-the-equation-x1+x2+x3-11-have-where-x1-x2-and-x3-are-Natural-Numbers)